# Dynamic control ID generation of ContentPage

Tags: html, webforms, master-pages, asp.net-4.0, content-pages

I'm stuck with this dynamic control ID generation,if I put my controls(say Button) in ContentPage (which is inherited by MasterPage) inside `<asp:Content></asp:Content>` when the page is rendered in the browser then the control Id are changed ,I read [ScottGu article on 'clientIDMode'](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx) and I thought my problem is over so I set 'clientIDMode' inside 'Web.Config'

```
<pages clientIDMode="Static"></pages>
```

But the problem persists I can't refer my controls from code behind like this,

```
        //ctl00$Cntnt$Button1 name works but its dynamically created
       if (ScriptManager1.AsyncPostBackSourceElementID == "Button1")
        {
            Label1.Text = "Async PostBack occured @ " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
```

**ASP.net Markup:**

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Refresh me" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

**Browser Side Markup:**

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$Cntnt$Button1" value="Refresh me" id="Button1" />
```

**Q)** Can't I use just the Id of controls which I have specified in the Markup (as if I don't have any MasterPage)?

**P.S:** On AsyncPostback I want to perform certain operations based on specific Button which made AsyncPostback ,to do that I have to check value from `AsyncPostBackSourceElementID` which unfortunately returns modified ControlID

Comment: What is the problem with letting ASP.NET handle the naming? You can still reference the control by the ID you specified, i.e. `Label1`.

Comment: @JamesJohnson But I can't refer Button1 by it's original name..!

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding the purpose of `ClientIDMode="Static"`. The IDs that are generated by ASP.NET only apply to the client-side. In the code-behind you can refer to the control by the ID you assigned to it in the markup. If this is not happening then you have another problem.

Comment: @JamesJohnson I want to perform certain operations based on specific Button which made AsyncPostback,to do that I have to check value from AsyncPostBackSourceElementID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ClientIDMode` doesn't matter because `AsyncPostBackSourceElementID` is actually returning the name of the button rather than the ID. However, you can easily get the name of the button through the `UniqueID` property:

```
if (ScriptManager1.AsyncPostBackSourceElementID == Button1.UniqueID)
{
    //do whatever
}
```

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of `ClientIDMode`. The IDs that ASP.NET generates apply to the client-side, and in the code-behind you can still access controls by the IDs assigned to them in markup.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

When this is rendered, a unique identifier (ClientID) will be generated for each control using a combination of the ID you assigned and the IDs of any ascendant naming containers. In this case `Panel1` is the naming container, so the generated ID would be:

```
<span id="ctl00_Panel1_Label1"></span>
```

However, in the code-behind you can still access the control by the original ID you assigned to it:

```
var labelText = Label1.Text;
```

The generated ID only comes into play on the client-side, where for example you might need to access the control from JavaScript; you would then can the ClientID to find it.

```
var labelText = document.getElementById("<%=Label1.ClientID%>").innerText;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying ,but that's not I'm asking for ,I have updated my question for clarification.

Comment: Button1.ClientID returns "Button1" and AsyncPostBackSourceElementID returns ctl00$Cntnt$Button1 ,this doesn't works :/

Comment: That's because you have `ClientIDMode` set to `Static`. It looks like it's returning the name of the button, which you can access using the `UniqueID` property of the control.

Comment: Use `UniqueID` to check against `AsyncPostBackSourceElementID`.